# Change the parameter values in a Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How to map the parameter values to a different value and then execute it inside the pipeline.

```
parameters {
      choice(name: 'SIMULATION_ID', 
        choices: 'GatlingDemoblaze\nFrontlineSampleBasic\nGatlingDemoStoreNormalLoadTest', 
        description: 'Simulations')
    }
```

How to map the value of 'GatlingDemoblaze' to '438740439023874' so that the it will be the latter which goes inside the ${params.SIMULATION_ID}? Can we do this with a simple groovy code?

```
gatlingFrontLineLauncherStep credentialId: '', simulationId:"${params.SIMULATION_ID}"
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It sounds like https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/ would be a good fit for your problem - it allows you to define key-value pairs for your choice parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Without using the plugin can we do it by only using the groovy code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the best approach will be to use the [Extensible Choice Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/) and define the needed key-value pairs, however if you don't want to use the plugin you can create the mapping using groovy in the pipeline script and use it.
For that you have several options:
If you need it for a single stage you can define the map inside a `script` block and use it in that stage:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'SIMULATION_ID',  description: 'Simulations',
                choices: ['GatlingDemoblaze', 'FrontlineSampleBasic', 'GatlingDemoStoreNormalLoadTest'])
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def mappings = ['GatlingDemoblaze': '111', 'FrontlineSampleBasic': '222', 'GatlingDemoStoreNormalLoadTest': '333']
                    gatlingFrontLineLauncherStep credentialId: '', simulationId: mappings[params.SIMULATION_ID]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also define it as a global parameter that will be available in all stages (and then you don't need the `script` directive):

```
mappings = ['GatlingDemoblaze': '111', 'FrontlineSampleBasic': '222', 'GatlingDemoStoreNormalLoadTest': '333']

pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'SIMULATION_ID',  description: 'Simulations',
                choices: ['GatlingDemoblaze', 'FrontlineSampleBasic', 'GatlingDemoStoreNormalLoadTest'])
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                gatlingFrontLineLauncherStep credentialId: '', simulationId: mappings[params.SIMULATION_ID]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and another options is to set these values in the `environment` directive:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(name: 'SIMULATION_ID',  description: 'Simulations',
                choices: ['GatlingDemoblaze', 'FrontlineSampleBasic', 'GatlingDemoStoreNormalLoadTest'])
    }
    environment{
        GatlingDemoblaze = '111'
        FrontlineSampleBasic = '222'
        GatlingDemoStoreNormalLoadTest = '333'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                gatlingFrontLineLauncherStep credentialId: '', simulationId: env[params.SIMULATION_ID]
            }
        }
    }
}
```